# How to show local time to the user in django?

Tags: python, django, timezone, django-timezone

I'm developing a Django app I have a model in which timestamps is added automatically.
I want to show the time to the end users according to their local timezone.

Here is my code:

settings.py

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

model.py

```
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

template

```
{{object.date_created}}
```

But it is showing UTC time I want this to detect user's current timezone and render date&time accordingly.

Comment: You can also use a front-end function to achieve similar results that might be more convenient for you, such as the `Date.now()` function inside javascript.

Answer (score -1):

The Django framework provides a built-in way to show local time to the user. When Django renders a template, it automatically passes in a variable called {{ localtime }} . This variable contains the current local time in the user's time zone.

If you want to display the local time in a specific format, you can use the Django template filter |date:"FORMAT" . For example, to display the local time in the "long" format, you would use the following code:

{{ localtime|date:"l, F jS Y H:i" }}

This would output something like "Sunday, January 1st 2017 12:00".

Comment: hmm this does not return anything for me. i put it in a simple p tag but it stays empty

Comment: There is a template tag and template filter named 'localtime' but no variable that provides a clients timezone information.

Comment: Django does not automatically collect timezone information from a client. It can be done manually by providing a form for the user or automatically using Javascript.